# Cómo utilizar '.each()' / 'for()' loop para cargar una lista dinámica de una matriz (array) en el DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Necesito hacer cargar dentro del ciclo `.each()` las imágenes de los productos en las divisiones de cada elemento `.Brand`.

Estoy tratando de utilizar el selector `$(this)` y cargar la etiqueta con la función HTML para cambiar las existentes.

Es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
var productos = new Array("afrodita.png",
"arpia.jpg",
"basilisco.jpg",
"caballo.jpg",
"centauro.jpg",
"fenix.jpg",
"gea.jpg",
"grifo.png",
"hidra.gif",
"kraken.jpg",
"medusa.png",
"minotauro.jpg",
"pegaso.jpg",
"poseidon.jpg",
"quimera.jpg",
"satiro.jpg",
"unicornio.jpg"
);

var t="";

window.onload=function(){
    //Cargar las imágenes en las divisiones
    $(".Brand").each(function(i,elemento){
        i = $(this).load("img/minis");
```

Comment: No me termina de quedar claro qué es lo que quieres. ¿Cómo está relacionado el array `productos` con el `each`? ¿qué es eso de "img/minis"?¿cómo tienes las imágenes ahora mismo?

Comment: el selector `.Brand` son elementos `img` o elementos `div`? Si son divs, tienen dentró únicamente una imagen o tienen más contenido? Pon tu html para entenderte mejor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si está intentando "imprimir" la lista `array` en el `documento` o en un elemento, puede hacerlo de esta manera usando un `for loop` que es lo mejor para el rendimiento:

> Puedes ver más sobre esta prueba de velocidad en este enlace: [Javascript for() loop vs jQuery .each() performance comparison](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.pt/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html).
>   Y ejecutar una prueba aquí: [Browser Diet - jQuery.each vs. for loop](https://jsperf.com/browser-diet-jquery-each-vs-for-loop).

## Usando Javascript puro & nativo `for() loop`:

```js
var productos = [
    "afrodita.png",
    "arpia.jpg",
    "basilisco.jpg",
    "caballo.jpg",
    "centauro.jpg",
    "fenix.jpg",
    "gea.jpg",
    "grifo.png",
    "hidra.gif",
    "kraken.jpg",
    "medusa.png",
    "minotauro.jpg",
    "pegaso.jpg",
    "poseidon.jpg",
    "quimera.jpg",
    "satiro.jpg",
    "unicornio.jpg"
],
    productosLength = productos.length,
    resultados = document.getElementById('resultados');

for (i = 0; i < productosLength; i++) {
    resultados.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="brand">'+productos[i]+'</div>');
}
```

```html
<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Sin embargo, si todavía desea utilizar la versión "[`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)", puede hacerlo así:

## Usando jQuery `.each()`:

```js
var productos = [
"afrodita.png",
"arpia.jpg",
"basilisco.jpg",
"caballo.jpg",
"centauro.jpg",
"fenix.jpg",
"gea.jpg",
"grifo.png",
"hidra.gif",
"kraken.jpg",
"medusa.png",
"minotauro.jpg",
"pegaso.jpg",
"poseidon.jpg",
"quimera.jpg",
"satiro.jpg",
"unicornio.jpg"
],
productosLength = productos.length;

$.each(productos, function(i, val){
  $('<div class="brand">'+val+'</div>').appendTo('#resultados');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultados"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".Brand").each(function(i,elemento){
    $(this).css('background-image',"url(img/minis/"+productos[i]+")");          
    i++;
    $(this).html(function (){
            $(".Brand").css("height",50);
            $(".Brand").css("width",50);

    });
});
```

Comment: Intenta explicar  lo que estas haciendo, de nada sirve dar una respuesta si no se conoce el porque. Aclara el codigo para que el usuario entienda que haces.